# .next() .prev() Traverse Through Multiple <article> elements

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio, tree-traversal

I'm working on a simple HTML5 audio playlist (audio.js) that changes to the next song in a Wordpress `<article ul li>` post. So I'm having a bit of trouble traversing through multiple `<article>` tags and retrieving the `<ul li>` of each on `.next()` and `.prev()`. I'm starting to think using these selectors is not the best solution.

```
<script>
  $(function() { 
    // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
    var a = audiojs.createAll({
      trackEnded: function() {
        var next = $('article ul li').next();
        var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
            $("a.songtitle").text(title);
        if (!next.length) next = $('article ul li').first();
        audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
        audio.play();
      }
    });

    // Load in the first track
    var audio = a[0];
        first = $('article ul a').attr('data-src');
    $('article ul li').first();
    audio.load(first);

    // Load in a track on click
    $('article ul li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
        $("a.songtitle").text(title);
      audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
      audio.play();
    });
    // Keyboard shortcuts
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
         // right arrow
      if (unicode == 39) {
        var next = $('article ul li').next();
        if (!next.length) next = $('ul li').first();
        next.click();
        // back arrow
      } else if (unicode == 37) {
        var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
            $("a.songtitle").text(title);
        var prev = $('article ul li').prev();
        if (!prev.length) prev = $('article ul li').last();
        prev.click();
        // spacebar
      } else if (unicode == 32) {
        audio.playPause();
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

How can I alter to this code to switch between multiple `<article ul li>` tags to skip to the next/prev song? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit:**
Here's what I'm trying to do. But as you can see it's not skipping songs to each `<article ul li>` tag. Audio.js automatically finds all `<a>` tags and gets the `data-src` attribute to load up a song. http://jsfiddle.net/UkrZx/

Comment: Why don't you create an array and then iterate through it instead of the actual DOM?

Comment: Please explain further, I'm totally n00bing it here. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: First of all, not everyone is familiar with what Wordpress articles look like, much less how your songlists are placed within them. So, how about creating a jsFiddle with some valid HTML?

Comment: Okay, thanks for that advice! Updated my original post as well. This is what I'm trying to do, but as you can see, they won't switch between <article ul li> elements. Audio.js automatically finds all <a> tags and gets the "data-src" attribute to load a song. http://jsfiddle.net/UkrZx/

Comment: So, you're saying that it only searches in a single `<article ui li>` tag?

Comment: Precisely, yes. Should I be using something like `nextAll();`?

Comment: Do you have control over how the `<audio>` files are posted to the articles? If you can post them as actual `<audio>` rather than `<a>`, I think I have a fix for you.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help on this DevlishOne. See my posted answer. Perhaps you can help me with my [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733513/html5-jquery-audio-shuffle-onclick), pertaining to shuffle songs using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why it wouldn't recognize next/prev `<article>` elements but I changed the original Wordpress post content to output the posts between just the `<li>` elements instead. Strange but at least it works now.

My code is now like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HxVaj/2/.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/y4yrJ/1/)

```
 $(function() { 
        // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
        var a = audiojs.createAll({
          trackEnded: function() {
            var next = $('article > ul li.playing').next();
            var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
                $("a.songtitle").text(title);
            if (!next.length) next = $('article > ul li').first();
            audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
            audio.play();
          }
        });

        // Load in the first track
        var audio = a[0];
            first = $('article > ul li a').attr('data-src');
        $('article > ul li').first();
        audio.load(first);

        // Load in a track on click
        $('article > ul li').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
            $("a.songtitle").text(title);
          audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
          audio.play();
        });
        // Keyboard shortcuts
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
             // right arrow
          if (unicode == 39) {
            var next = $('article > ul li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('article > ul li').first();
            next.click();
            // back arrow
          } else if (unicode == 37) {
            var title = $('img', this).attr("title");
                $("a.songtitle").text(title);
            var prev = $('article > ul li.playing').prev();
            if (!prev.length) prev = $('article > ul li').last();
            prev.click();
            // spacebar
          } else if (unicode == 32) {
            audio.playPause();
          }
        })
      });
```

It looks like you were trying to modify [THIS SCRIPT](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) and I wish I knew more about Wordpress or the AUDIO.JS script to help you. It doesn't seem to want to recognize anything outside the parent `<li>` but I can get it to play the second song in your code. Good luck, I hope this helps.

**edit** minor accomplishment... with a few edits (and a an updated fiddle), I can get it to play both songs but only with the left arrow. Weird, I know.. but it's progress.

Comment: That's alright, thanks for trying. That's the exact script I'm trying to modify. Do you think it has something to do with the of `.next()` and `.prev();` selectors? I read that these selectors only  traverse through the next element in a set.

Comment: The addition of the `<article > ` should expand the set to include an `article` tag as the outermost element and any that contain an `ul li`, so no. I'll read through the AUDIO.JS docs and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help on this DevlishOne. See my posted answer. Perhaps you can help me with my [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733513/html5-jquery-audio-shuffle-onclick)?