# HTML5/jQuery audio shuffle onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, html5-audio

I have a simple HTML5 audio playlist and I would like the user to click a "shuffle" button and shuffle the audio but I don't know the best way to go about this. I'm using [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) for HTML5 audio.

http://jsfiddle.net/HxVaj/4/

As you can see in the fiddle, audio.js grabs the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` to play an audio file in the player at the top. The shuffle button would need to pick a random `<li a>` on click.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic for shuffle button.  You'll have to write in the code to the get the track to play but it shouldn't be that difficult.  I added a class to the ul called "tracks".

```
 $(".shufflebutton").click(function() {
        var trackCount = $(".tracks li").length;
        console.log('trackCount:' + trackCount);
         /* Pick random number between 1 and trackCount */
        var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*trackCount); 
        console.log("randomNum:" + randomNum);     
      });
```

Full code example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/F8w8r/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I didn't notice any changes in the fiddle you provided me. I tried to implement the code you gave me but no dice. Take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/F8w8r/2/

Comment: I made a few minor updates.  Check out the updated .shufflebutton logic:  http://jsfiddle.net/F8w8r/3/